# VS2012 debugging server side code with Google Chrome

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, visual-studio-2012

I work on an asp.net mvc app.

This morning I was able to debug my server side code from a Google Chrome browser instance. I simply select `Google Chrome` in place of `Internet Explorer` in my VS2012 then click on it to run the app. When a breakpoint was reached (for example in my controller) it switch automatically to VS2012 for debugging.

This afternoon I am not able to do it again with Google Chrome. Only able to debug with Internet Explorer.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Is your breakpoint in a javascript file?  I think that's the only way what your describing is possible.

Comment: No the breakpoints was on server side code (C# controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't matter which browser you tell VS to open your website in. If your debugger is attached to your C# your breakpoints should be hit as long as you're using the correct URI defined by your MVC app. I use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) to debug my controllers all the time. Are you sure you didn't make any changes that would cause Chrome to make an incorrect request? Or perhapse the browser has cached old code and that's why the breakpoints are not being hit? I always open Chrome with **ctrl + shift N** to avoid having any caching issues.

Comment: I didn't make any changes to my code and I always use Chrome without cache (Disable cache while DevTools is open). So you confirm this is possible do debug server side code in my controller when running with Chrome ? I mean setting a breakpoint on 1 statement inside 1 method's controller and having the execution stopped when this statement is reached ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Are you still having trouble?

Comment: So far so good, I don't know why previously this was problematic but now I can debug (hit breakpoints in my controllers) through Google Chrome. Thanks.